# How to get the error message on blur of input field inside onfocusout function

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I was just trying to use validate.js for one of my small projects , what i was most impressed was the amount of customization options this plugin gives you, Now what i really wanted to do is , i have the below validation code:

```
$('#testimonials-form').validate({
        rules: {
            "t-title": {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            "t-text": {
                required: true,
                minlength: 15
            },
            "person-name": {
                required: true,
                minlength: 4
            },
            "photo": {
                required: true,
                accept: 'image/*'
            }
        },
        messages: {
            "t-title": {
                required: "A title is needed",
                minlength: "minimum 4 characters"
            },
            "t-text": {
                required: "A testimonial is needed",
                minlength: "minimum 15 characters"
            },
            "person-name": {
                required: "A name is needed",
                minlength: "minimum 4 characters"
            },
            "photo" : {
                required: "An image for the testimonial giver is needed",
                accept: "Only image file type is accpeted , please check that the file you tried to upload was an image"
            }
        },

        submitHandler: function(form) {
                return false;
        },

    });
```

now everytime i focusOut of a input field, and the validation cretiria is not met , the error is shown at the bottom of the input feild , what i wanted was a customized error message , so i came across the following function in the documentation **[HERE](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#onfocusout)** , the `onfocusout` function, now if i use that function like below:

```
        onfocusout: function(e , b) {
          var exe = e.target;
          var b = null;
        }
```

The default validation message stops appearing , but than how do i get the error message inside the onfocusout function, so that i can display the error in my customized HTML , I.E. the below error messages:

```
messages: {
            "t-title": {
                required: "A title is needed",
                minlength: "minimum 4 characters"
            },
            "t-text": {
                required: "A testimonial is needed",
                minlength: "minimum 15 characters"
            },
            "person-name": {
                required: "A name is needed",
                minlength: "minimum 4 characters"
            },
            "photo" : {
                required: "An image for the testimonial giver is needed",
                accept: "Only image file type is accpeted , please check that the file you tried to upload was an image"
            }
        },
```

The two parameters passed by the plugin to `onfocusout` function are:

1. the element.
2. the event object.

(checked the above in the console.)

So my question is , how do i get the error message on blur of the input field ? or is it not possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onfocusout` IS enabled by default.  However, the validation is "lazy" by default.  This means that tabbing through the fields does nothing until after the first click of the submit.  See the second bullet point [here](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/#link-a-few-things-to-look-out-for-when-playing-around-with-the-demo).

> Before a field is marked as invalid, the validation is lazy: Before submitting the form for the first time, the user can tab through fields without getting annoying messages – they won't get bugged before having the chance to actually enter a correct value

Click submit first and then see `onfocusout` functional...

**Default:  http://jsfiddle.net/31fjzogp/**

---

When you specify the `onfocusout` option within your object literal, you completely over-ride the default functionality.

I'm not sure what you have going on in here...

```
onfocusout: function(e , b) {
    var exe = e.target;
    var b = null;
}
```

As per the source code, the developer only provides one argument for this function, so `b` is going to do nothing for you.  Even if `b` was the event object, setting it to `null` would also do nothing.  Basically, your custom function simply disables `onfocusout` entirely.

> So my question is , how do i get the error message on blur of the input field ? or is it not possible ?

To switch the `onfocusout` from "lazy" to "eager"...

```
onfocusout: function(element) {
    this.element(element);
}
```

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/3pLr49rs/**

---

> The default validation message stops appearing, but than how do i get the error message inside the onfocusout function, so that i can display the error in my customized HTML.

They stopped appearing when you broke the default `onfocusout` function, and you would **not** put messages *inside* of the the `onfocusout` function.

As you can see, the `messages` option works fine as you've implemented it: http://jsfiddle.net/3pLr49rs/1/

To customize the placement or HTML of the message container, you would use options such as [`errorPlacement`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#errorplacement), [`errorElement`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#errorelement), etc.  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/3pLr49rs/2/

Comment: Wow thanks but what is `this.element(element);` really doing ?

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik, it's triggering a validation test of the element.  See:  [jqueryvalidation.org/Validator.element/](http://jqueryvalidation.org/Validator.element/) ~ If you look at the source code of the plugin, you will see this same code used within the default `onfocusout` function.

Comment: lol this is really stupid of me , your answer taught me alot , what i really wanted was , how do i get the error msg inside the function , so i can generate my own HTML and append it to the element !

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik, you do not put the error messages inside the function!  You would use the options of the plugin to change the HTML as per your needs.  See `errorPlacement`, `errorElement`, etc.

Comment: Thanks alot for your time .